# How to find and delete duplicate lines in two files in vi editor or linux

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, vi

I have 2 files A and B. both have more than 100 lines. I want to delete common lines between both the files.
A:

```
asdf123
fdsa123
rrrr456
yyyy555
```

B:

```
fdsa123
hhhh888
yyyy555
```

So now the files should be
A1:

```
asdf123
rrrr456
```

B1:

```
hhhh888
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -vf a b    # or   grep -vf a b > b1   to save it
hhhh888

$ grep -vf b a    # or   grep -vf b a > a1   to save it
asdf123
rrrr456
```

Note that `grep -f file1 file2` checks the lines from `file1` that appear in `file2`. That is, gets the patterns from the `file1`.

Then, `grep -v` stands for invert match. That is, to get the opposite result as the `grep` command.

Comment: It is worth noticing that by default grep matches lines with regular expressions, which is not desired in this case. 
You need to add **-F** parameter so that grep compare lines as plain strings: 
`grep -Fvf file1 file2`

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
awk -f del.awk fileA fileB > fileB.del
awk -f del.awk fileB fileA > fileA.del
```

where `del.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]++
    next
}

! ($0 in a) {
    print
}
```